# How to find out where bootstrap-material is created

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap-Material](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html) in my website.

I'm having a problem getting the checkbox to work. When I copy the code from the Bootstrap-Material site to my project, most of the features work, but no Box appears beside the label "Checkbox". Instead of looking like

[image: material checkobx]

it looks like

[image: checkbox material]

I've been going through the source code on the [Bootstrap-Material](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html) and I've imported all the `css` and `js` they have.

What's confusing is, I've inspected the elements on the Checkbox of the [Bootstrap-Material page](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html) and I can't figure out what `css` or `js` file is actually creating the checkbox. It doesn't seem to be coming from an image file, so where is it coming from? Perhaps if I can figure out where it is created, I can figure out why my project is not rendering it.

Any ideas on where this box comes from?

Comment: take a look around roughly here in the source: https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/blob/master/dist/css/material.css#L3797

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check:

1: Are you calling `$.material.init()` to active Material Design.
2: Are your CSS files stacked with Material Design before the Bootstrap v3.0+ file.
3: You're using jQuery 1.9.1+.

```js
$.material.init()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/material.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <h1 class="header">Checkbox</h1>

  <!-- Simple checkbox with label -->
  <div class="sample1">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Notifications</label>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turns out I was missing `$.material.init`. I added `window.onload = function(){$.material.init();};` and now it works!

Comment: Slight issue; I'm using this in Angular with ui-router, and each time I go to a new page it stops working, until I refresh the page. Any idea why? Do I have to somehow reload it at each new path?

Comment: Honestly, I've never used the two together but maybe this will help: https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/191

Comment: I don't know why but it stopped working again... where did you get that css from?

Comment: never mind... works now that I put the css after the js as you did

Comment: thank you,I'll try after ajax load container.So faster worked,than page load .